# Sqoop not working with Oozie (HUE)

Tags: sqoop, oozie

I'm trying to execute a sqoop command using Hue but fails. Part of the log is:

```
Sqoop command arguments :
             --
             import
             --connect
             jdbc:oracle:thin:@orps:1522:con12
             --username
             sqa
             --password
             ********
             --query
             'SELECT
             *
             FROM
             TARQ32
             WHERE
             $CONDITIONS'
             --split-by
             MO_NUMLINE
             --as-sequencefile
             --target-dir
             /user/pes9/oracle/L12
             -m
             8
Fetching child yarn jobs
tag id : oozie-365c82c0bacd9831582dfe7edb354dfb
2017-11-13 15:47:50,208 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy  - Connecting to ResourceManager at xxx.yyyy.net/10.4.58.61:8032
Child yarn jobs are found - 
=================================================================

>>> Invoking Sqoop command line now >>>

2017-11-13 15:47:50,387 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.

<<< Invocation of Sqoop command completed <<<

No child hadoop job is executed.
Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
```

I tried to copy the ojdbc.jar in oozie lib, hdfs sharedlib, and other locations but nothing works. The same issue happend with Spark jobs executions, when I create a workflow and execute a spark job I'm getting thi error:

```
   Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [1]
```

Any idea?

[Update]

Stderr

```
          Nov 13, 2017 3:47:44 PM com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule$BackwardsCompatibleServletContextProvider get
WARNING: You are attempting to use a deprecated API (specifically, attempting to @Inject ServletContext inside an eagerly created singleton. While we allow this for backwards compatibility, be warned that this MAY have unexpected behavior if you have more than one injector (with ServletModule) running in the same JVM. Please consult the Guice documentation at http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets for more information.
Nov 13, 2017 3:47:44 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Nov 13, 2017 3:47:44 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Nov 13, 2017 3:47:44 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
Nov 13, 2017 3:47:44 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Nov 13, 2017 3:47:44 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Nov 13, 2017 3:47:45 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Nov 13, 2017 3:47:45 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Can you please post what the error that you can see in stderr file of oozie launcher logs.

Comment: I just updated the original message with the stderr

Comment: How did you fix this?